# make UIAccessibilityTrait adjustable ignore double-tap (like a button) swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I have a custom control to increment and decrement values. Now that I've added support for voice over, I've stumbled upon a problem. 
My customView has the accessibility trait `.adjustable` and I implemented the correct methods for increasing and decreasing the values. 
However, the voice over user can also double tap on that view to activate it. The problem is, that this triggers a gesture which is irrelevant to voice over users.

Is there a way to prevent an adjustable accessibility view from being activated so that the element is only adjustable, not double-tappable like a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning to stop any tasks which would be triggered by a doubletap on that specific element.

Comment: good idea hoping that this kind of task isn't used for another element somewhere in your app where double-tap is allowed.  ;o)

Answer (score 1):

There are two important properties to know when a double-tap occurs:

- [accessibilityActivate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615165-accessibilityactivate).
- [accessibilityActivationPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615179-accessibilityactivationpoint).

In your case, you could just return true by overriding `accessibilityActivate` and if it's not enough, provide as well a CGPoint coordinate that triggers nothing *(depends of your custom control and its neighborhood)*.

Otherwise, use the `accessibilityElementIsFocused` instance method to know wether you can trigger actions as this [complete example](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#focus-an-element) shows up.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I ended up using UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning to stop any tasks which would be triggered by a doubletap.